# GL/CL interoperability: Shared Texture

Tags: opengl, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I intend to make Graphics calculation with OpenCL such as ray casting, ray marching and others. And I want to use OpenGL to display result of this calculations (pixel images). I use texture buffer attached to frame buffer. OpenCL writes the result into the texture and then I use glBlitFrameBuffer function to copy texture data to application window framebuffer.
I met a CL/GL inter problem during the implementation of it. I wrote a simple example to show it. This example shows framebuffer object and texture object initialization, their conjunction, OpenCL buffer creation from GL texture buffer. At the end the main render loop is shown. It consists of texture writing with new data in each frame, framebuffer attachment and copying of this framebuffer.

Texture Initialization:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i +=4) {
    data [i] = 255;
}
GL.BindTexture (TextureTarget.Texture2D, tboID [0]);
GL.TexImage2D<byte>(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba8, w, h, 0,
                    PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data);
GL.BindTexture (TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0)
```

TBO+FBO Initialization:

```
 GL.BindFramebuffer (FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, fboID [0]);
 GL.FramebufferTexture2D (FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0,
                          TextureTarget.Texture2D, tboID [0], 0);
 GL.BindFramebuffer (FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, 0);
```

CL/GL Initialization:

```
bufferID = CL.CreateFromGLTexture2D (context, memInfo, textureTarget, mipLevel, glBufferObject, out errorCode);
```

Render Loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 4) {
     data [i] = tt;
 }
 tt++;
 GL.BindTexture (TextureTarget.Texture2D, tboID [0]);
 GL.TexImage2D<byte> (TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba8, w, h, 0,
                      PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data);

 GL.BindTexture (TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0);
 GL.BindFramebuffer (FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, fboID [0]);
 GL.FramebufferTexture2D (FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0,
                          TextureTarget.Texture2D, tboID [0], 0);
 GL.BindFramebuffer (FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, 0);GL.BindFramebuffer (FramebufferTarget.ReadFramebuffer, fboID [0]);

 GL.ReadBuffer (ReadBufferMode.ColorAttachment0);
 GL.DrawBuffer (DrawBufferMode.Back);

 GL.BlitFramebuffer (0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w, h, ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit, BlitFramebufferFilter.Nearest);

 GL.BindFramebuffer (FramebufferTarget.ReadFramebuffer, 0);
```

At the first glance this code looks weird, but it completely shows my problem. CL does not work at all here. In this application OpenCL context is created and OpenCL buffer initialization is occured.
The work of this should be simple. The color of screen is being changed from black to red. And It does not work in this way. The color does not change from the initial red (texture initialization).
But it works normal when I comment the CL/GL Initialization (creation of CL buffer from GL texture).
Why is it so? Why the behavior of the GL buffer is changed depending on CL attachments? How to fix it and make it works?

Comment: I can eventually confirm this behaviour, as soon as there's a Image2DGL object bound to a texture, the texture is blocked and cannot be written to or from another context. This is on an nvidia device as well. Question arises, why there is an explicit `acquire` and `release` if it's blocked anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we were able to run Itun' code on my system (Windows 7 / AMD Radeon HD 5870). Recall that Itun' code gradually changes color in **texture** from black to red **by means of GL after activating GL/CL Interop on this texture**.

The results are at least strange. On my system it works as intended. However, on Itun' system (Windows 7 / NVidia GeForce) the same code does not work at all and does not provide any exceptions or error codes. In addition, I would like to mention that CL works with this texture properly on both systems. Therefore, something is wrong with GL in this case.

We have no idea on what's going on - it could be either Itun' outdated GPU hardware or buggy NVidia drivers.

Comment: Just for the record: What nVidia chip do you have?

Comment: Also, it would have been nice to know what you had to change to get rid of that wrong image descriptor using your amd card...

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT 2:**

Then you need to check why you are getting an `InvalidImageFormatDescriptor`. Check if the parameter order is okay and whether your image descriptor in the tbo is misleading (internal image structure - see OpenCL specification). From the spec:

> CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR if the OpenGL texture internal format does not map to a supported OpenCL image format.

---

**EDIT:**

So I understand OpenCL functionality in OpenTK is provided by a separate project named Cloo. For `ComputeImage2D` their documentation states:

```
CreateFromGLTexture2D (ComputeContext context, ComputeMemoryFlags flags, int textureTarget, int mipLevel, int textureId)
```

Compared to yours:

```
CreateFromGLTexture2D (context, MemFlags.MemReadWrite, TextureTarget.Texture2D, ((uint[])tboID.Clone()) [0], 0);
```

Looking at that you have the mip level and the `tbo` in the wrong order. A false initialization might lead to some unknown behaviour.

---

Hard to tell what might be the issue from the code you're providing. Am looking at the Interop as well right now, just getting into it. First thing I would try is put a try/catch block around it and try to get a clue about any possible [error code](https://github.com/smistad/OpenCLUtilities/blob/master/openCLUtilities.cpp).

Have you verified the obvious: Is the `cl_khr_gl_sharing` extension available on your device?

Another guess, since you only provided the Texture/Image Initialisation of the actual OpenCl/OpenGL Interop within your sample code: Did you acquire the memory object?

```
cl_int clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects (cl_command_queue command_queue,
  cl_uint num_objects.
  const cl_mem *mem_objects,
  cl_uint num_events_in_wait_list,
  const cl_event *event_wait_list,
  cl_event *event)
```

The [OpenCL 1.1 specifiction](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects.html) states:

> The function `cl_int clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects` is used to acquire OpenCL memory objects that have been created from OpenGL objects. These
>   objects need to be acquired before they can be used by any OpenCL commands queued to a
>   command-queue. The OpenGL objects are acquired by the OpenCL context associated with
>   command_queue and can therefore be used by all command-queues associated with the OpenCL
>   context.

So the issue might be that the memory object hasn't been bound to  a specific command queue.

Also, one is responsible for issuing a `glFinish()` to ensure all the initialization on the OpenGL side is done before the memory object is acquired.

Comment: Itun' example is pretty simple - as you can see CL is not even used there - only GL. Therefore, neither `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects` nor `glFinish` are needed. The essence of the problem is `CL.CreateFromGLTexture2D` call, after which "Render Loop" snippet stops working (and again "Render Loop" sample uses only GL). For instance, on my system (Radeon HD 5870) I get `System.Exception: CL Error has occured: InvalidImageFormatDescriptor`. On Itun' system, suprisingly (NVidia GeForce <whatever>), we have no exception - GL simply stops working properly.

Comment: Looks like if `CL.CreateFromGLTexture2D` would cause some interference. Anyway many combinations (like using `glFinish`) were already tested. The solution is yet to come. It would be great if someone could test similar code on their own platforms and provide some feedback.

Comment: As I mentioned, I assumed that not all the code regarding the OpenCL part is shown (and therefore did not attempt to test the code). The OP states that he wanted to do calculations like ray casting with OpenCL, so I checked for possible left outs in the initialization of the CL/GL interop chain.

Comment: You seem to know his problem, so what's the sense of CL/GL interop then?

Comment: The sense is that we want to use CL/GL interop in order to: (1) do computations with CL and let CL write results to texture buffer; (2) use GL to "`BlitFramebuffer`" the resulted texture directly to frame buffer. However, when we activate interop for texture with `CL.CreateFromGLTexture2D` - we are not able to do anything with this texture neither in GL nor in CL.

Comment: Look at the Itun' code. His code works fine if we remove `CL.CreateFromGLTexture2D` call (which activates interop on texture). I. e. the color in texture will gradually change from black to red. In contrast, as soon as we make `CL.CreateFromGLTexture2D` call - GL gets confused somehow and does not change color in texture anymore. The key fact is that we are not even using CL yet - we just activate CL/GL interop and all the texture business is related to GL only! However, after activating this interop on the texture - GL stops working properly with this texture - as shown in the Itun' code.

Comment: What are you using? Is this JOCL?

Comment: I know I could have asked earlier, but please provide that information within the question. I was going to suggest a mix up in the signature before realizing, you were obviously using something else. I have zero experience of how OpenTK behaves with OpenCL issues.

Comment: Well it does not matter - API is the same everywhere. OpenTK simply did the routine of importing CL and GL functions from DLL and wrapping them according to C# rules.

Comment: If it's not that what I stated in my edit, then I'm sorry, I wouldn't know how to help in this.

Comment: That's because we don't use Cloo. OpenTK is sufficient to use OpenCL in C# in the same manner as in C/C++. Cloo just extend OpenTK with some sugar wrapper (which has bugs btw). Anyway we don't use Cloo.

Comment: rdoubleui, I'm sorry for the mess in my post (refer to your Edit 1). I edited the code lines in CL/GL Initialization. The argument order was right in my project.

Comment: I also want to add that I have no exceptions and no CL errors (I check all CL calls).